# Maximize the metric norm over a convex set

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, conic-sections, non-convex-optimization

Given a convex function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$, let $C$ be a sublevel set of $f$, e.g. $C = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \leq 1 \right\rbrace$. Its easy to prove that $C$ is a convex set.

Given an ellipsoid $E = (Q,c)$ such that for $a > 0$
$$ C \subseteq a \cdot (E - c) + c$$
i.e. enlarging $E$ by $a$, will yield an ellipsoid which contains $C$.

The problem is that we want to find a point $x \in C$ such that it maximizes the following term:
$$ \left\| L(x-c)\right\|_2$$
where $L$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $Q$ where $Q$ is the matrix which represents the ellipsoid.

This function is *NP-Hard* since this problem is non-convex optimization problem, also there might be  more than one local maximum rather than exactly one as in convex optimization problems.

Lately I have stumbled upon a presentation where they tried to maximize a convex function over a convex set (specifically polytope), using the maximum inscribed ellipsoid: [Maximizing Norm](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme334/docs/2011-11-17-Rubira_normmax.pdf)

I wonder whether is it possible to apply similar methods or is there a polynomial algorithm for solving the problem and guaranteeing a global maximum?